# Toggle autoscroll of ListView - when scrolled interactively by user

Tags: android, android-listview, autoscroll, android-scroll

I have a real app - which you can see on the left in the below screenshot.

And I have prepared [a very simple test app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q16/MyScroll) at GitHub, which you can see at the right:

[image: screenshot]

The real app has a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) at the bottom, which is filled with Bluetooth-related log messages. This happens pretty often, few times a second and **it is impossible for the user to scroll up and look at a particular event** - because the list jumps to the bottom by itself, when new events are added to the list.

My question is: **How to disable autoscrolling of the `ListView` - when user scrolls up and how to enable autoscrolling again, when user scrolls to the bottom?**

And here is my very simple test app:

- [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q16/MyScroll/src/de/afarber/myscroll/MainActivity.java) (filling the ListView with help of AsyncTask)
- [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q16/MyScroll/res/layout/activity_main.xml) (layout with Button and ListView)

As you can see the auto-scrolling is currently enabled by XML attributes in layout:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found a perfect solution for my problem:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When the [transcriptMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode) is set to **normal**, then:

> The list will automatically scroll to the bottom when a data set
>   change notification is received and only if the last item is already
>   visible on screen.

Here is [my updated test project](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyScroll) (I've also added double tap listener to clear the `ListView` there)

[image: screenshot]